# image picker can't be used in this class

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I got a problem in `imagepicker` which is pick image is red underlined which mean undefined class.
[image]

anyone can give the solution?

here is my code:

```
class _homepageState extends State<homepage> {
String? _path = null;

void _showPhotoLibrary() async {
 final file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

 setState(() {
   _path = file!.path;
 });

 void _showCamera() async {
   final cameras = await availableCameras();
   final camera = cameras.first;

   final result = await Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => TakePicturePage(camera: camera)));

   setState(() {
     _path = result;
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize `ImagePicker` like this

```
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

Then you can access `pickImage`

Answer (score 0):

```
I Used This code for image_picker its working fine for me please try this way hope this works for you

///first you have to create this line 
File ?_image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

////alertbox to choose image from gallery or camera
 Future<void>_showChoiceDialog(BuildContext context)
  {
    return showDialog(context: context,builder: (BuildContext context){

      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Choose option",style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: [
              Divider(height: 1,color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,),
              ListTile(
                onTap: (){
                  _getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                },
                title: Text("Gallery",style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),),
                leading: Icon(Icons.account_box,color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,),
              ),

              Divider(height: 1,color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,),
              ListTile(
                onTap: (){
                  _getImage(ImageSource.camera,);
                },
                title: Text("Camera",style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),),
                leading: Icon(Icons.camera,color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),);
    });
  }

////to show image from image picker 
 Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width:_width,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 120,
                            width: 120,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                image:  FileImage(_image!),
                              ),
                              border: Border.all(color: AppColors.white, width: 2.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

////cretae a method to get image
 _getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async
  {
    PickedFile? imageFile = await picker.getImage(source: imageSource);
//if user doesn't take any image, just return.
    if (imageFile == null) return;
    setState(
          () {
//Rebuild UI with the selected image.
        _image = File(imageFile.path);
      },
    );
  }
```